# Referencing error in Microsoft Word 2010

Tags: microsoft-word

Word 2010 comes with a list of default referencing styles. But on  my computer the ribbon is blanked out. How do I fix this?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the style directory located at

> `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\<office version>\Bibliography\Style`

If the style directory is either empty or non-existent, you may have a borked installation.
Reinstall Office

for more information see this thread:
http://www.pchelpforum.com/office-software/49655-word-2007-citations-referencing.html

Comment: I have C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office 2010 ,but no Bibliography\Style inside that

Comment: It sounds like you will need to reinstall office